# Google pie chart api font size

Tags: pie-chart

I am using google pie chart API using PHP and want to increase the font size in the chart. I found we can use 'chdls' to increase the font size but its not working... i am using this url

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=300x200&cht=p3&chl=Won|Draw|Lost&chd=t:6.0,3.0,1.0&chtt=Pie+chart+for+TalkPHP's+soccerteam|By+maZtah&chco=ff0099&chdls=18

Answer (score 0):

options.pieSliceTextStyle     = {fontSize:11};

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the font size of Chart title by using the below code:

```
chts=FF0000,20,r
```

(chdls is used for legend size, colors ONLY)